# Prevent overwriting of chrome extension source file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, extension

I recently had to upgrade my chrome from 73 to 92 version. I used only one extension with a little bit of modification in the source code. It was working fine with version 73, however with version 92 my modification gets overwritten by each restart or more frequently.

Is there any way to prevent this overwriting? So I can modify the extension as my wish.

I guess this is a security feature, however I'd like to disable it as I use only this extension.

The name of the extension is: Copy All Urls.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the extension?

Comment: Nope, but it sounds to be a good idea. Can You help me how to do that? I guess it's not enough to rename it in the options.html file.

Comment: No idea, I've never modified an extension in Chrome.